# How to set primary key when linking with CreateTableDef

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In a MS Access database, I'm connecting to views in a SQL Server database like this:

```
Dim s  As String
s = "ODBC;DSN=mydb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=mydb;"

Dim td As TableDef
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("vwMyView", 0, "MySchema.vwMyView", s)

CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
```

This creates a linked table, which is linked to a view in SQL Server.

However, I **cannot insert/update/delete**, because Access does not know the "primary key". How can the information about the primary key added in VBA ?

When using the Linked Table Wizard, you are always asked to select the unique key columns from a listbox. I want to reproduce this behaviour in VBA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always update the table you just attached to include an Index/Primary key. Something like,

```
Dim s  As String
s = "ODBC;DSN=mydb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=mydb;"

Dim td As TableDef
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("vwMyView", 0, "MySchema.vwMyView", s)

CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td

CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SomeIndex ON vwMyView (PrimaryKeyColumn) WITH PRIMARY".

CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh

Set td = Nothing
```

Not sure if you need to refresh the CurrentDB before creating an INDEX. Try refreshing without first, if it does not work - refresh it then Execute the CREATE statement.

Comment: YES that works!!  I totally forgot that you have DDL Statements also in MS Access. Man, that saves me so much time now  -- Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE INDEX <YourIndexName> ON <YourTableName>(<YourFieldName>) WITH PRIMARY
```

Comment: Here, too --- YES that works!!  I totally forgot that you have DDL Statements also in MS Access. Man, that saves me so much time now  -- Thanks a lot!