# Setting primary key for SQL Server view linked to Access front end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server view linked to an Access front end.  The view is updatable in SQL Server Management Studio, but not currently updatable through Access.  After some research, it seems that I might need to specify the primary key in Access for the view in order for Access to be able to modify records in the view.

I came across this

[How to set primary key when linking with CreateTableDef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915181/how-to-set-primary-key-when-linking-with-createtabledef)

which shows in the responses a couple of different approaches to setting the primary key.  These two approaches are as follows:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SomeIndex ON vwMyView (PrimaryKeyColumn) WITH PRIMARY".
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX <YourIndexName> ON <YourTableName>(<YourFieldName>) WITH PRIMARY
```

I am confused by the different specification of the "index" and the "field"/"column" names.  If the column in my view that I want to be the primary key is myID, does that get specified as the index or field, or both?  If not both, what is the other name?

Is the period at the end of the first approach a typo?  I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Have you tried both? What happened?

Comment: I can't try them because I don't know what to specify for index and field/column.  Hence this question.

Comment: Sorry, I think you meant have I tried specifying both as myID.  No I haven't.  I'm new to this, and not entirely sure if executing a random command will set something I don't know how to undo.  So waiting for more info.

Comment: You wrote "...does that get specified as the index or field, or both?" so you should try those things before asking.  If you don't know how to undo something then you have larger problems than creating an index because you should be properly backed up before trying a solution that a stranger gives you on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX <YourIndexName> ON <YourTableName>(<YourColumnName>) WITH PRIMARY
```

- `<YourIndexName>` = Any name you want, this will be used by Access
- `<YourTableName>` = The name of your table in Access
- `<YourColumnName>` = The name of the column in the table

Comment: That did it!  Our views are now updatable in Access.