# Access linked to SQL Server shows #Name? in fields after filtering

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, view

Regarding:

- MS Access 2016
- SQL Server 2017

I have an ODBC connection to a local SQL Server. Works like a charm. Two of the linked tables are made as views. When I open the view in MS Access, it shows figure 1. When I apply a filter, I get the results shown in figure 2, with error in all fields as `#Name?`

It works perfectly fine when I look it up directly in SQL Server.

Any suggestions?

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

Comment: There is an error message, have you analyzed that? -- Can you scroll to the end of the unfiltered view without error?

Comment: What's the filter?

Comment: The filter is just "Project" = "LS10005" or similar. When i scroll all the way down without filter, i get the same result - Each cell turns to #Name?

Comment: I think you need to fix the error first.

Comment: Try filtering with `'LS10005'` instead of `LS10005`. It shouldn't make any difference but it doesn't hurt to try. Another issue may be the possible lack of a Primary Key. There is a lot of Access table functionality that simply does not work with MS SQL Views linked as tables, most of which is solved if you assign a primary key to the linked table upon linking.

Comment: *When i scroll all the way down without filter, i get the same result - Each cell turns to #Name* -- then there is a row with data that Access cannot process. Filtering has nothing to do with the error, it just makes it show up earlier.

Comment: In Sql Server, check your numeric columns for unusual values (sort by each). What numeric data types are you using?

Comment: @SunKnight0 Both parent tables in the linked table view has a primary key. How do i assign a primary key to the view only?

Comment: @Andre The table has 65000 rows - How do i check for unusual values and what should i look for?

Comment: All: I found the error, i think. I had to change all "Yes/No" fields when migrating from Access to SQL Server 2017. I tried with "Bit" but that didnt work when i wanted to edit a record. Thats a question for another time. Anyway, i chose to go with "Int" as it seemed to work. However, some pieces of the code still insert -1 if "Yes", into the "Int" field. The error dissapear when i manualle change all -1 to 1 in the DB. But why is that? Shouldnt the Int by default be signed? Should go from  -2^31 to 2^31 ?

Comment: I use `bit`. True still evaluates as -1 in Access, even though its real value is 1 in SQL server. The main advantage of using bit is that checkboxes bound to bit fields work properly. As for adding a PK, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915181/how-to-set-primary-key-when-linking-with-createtabledef

Answer (score 2):

Add what is called a "row version" column to the table. 
So, create a timestamp column in the base table that the view is based on. Now include that new column - useally I call it TS, but it is going to be of type "timestamp" - not to be confused with a date/time column.

The table likely has 1 or more floating point columns, or perhaps a timestamp column. So, add the timestamp column to the base table. Add the TS column to the view, and then re-link the view (or refresh -don't forget this last step).

When you link the view (manually with the access UI), you are given a one-time chance to select the PK column. You should not necessary need to set (choose) the PK column, but if you don't, then the table will be read only (and that is fine).

If above TS column does not fix this, then do try choosing a PK when you link (so, a refresh will not suffice, you have to delete and re-create the linked view to get (force/trigger) that all important prompt for the PK. As noted, adding a TS column should fix this, but if it does not, then start over, and re-create the linked view  with both a PK selected, and also that all important TS column. If you don't include the TS column, then Access (client side) will do a ugly field by field compare - using a TS column will eliminate this extra work, and rather likely your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just one question: My view is a joined view of two tables. Where should i put the TS column?

Comment: Note: Right now i use the "ID" column from base table A as PK in Access. "ID" is autonumber.

Comment: All tables need a PK to function correctly with Access. Views do NOT support concept of a PK. Thus you are prompted to choose the PK when linking a view as opposed to when linking a table. If you need the View to be up-dateable, then you MUST choose a PK during the linking process. (if  you don't need read/write ability, then skipping this step is no big deal).. Thus all tables need a PK and all tables should have a TS column added. For 20 years the up-sizing tools for Access to sql server have always included a TS generate option. So all tables should have TS columns - (of type timestamp).

Comment: So, add a TS column to both tables.